# Encrypting data in php and decryption in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am working with 2 servers.

I want to create a pair of keys and store the private key in local storage and send the public key to PHP server.

basically encryption of data with the public key in PHP and decryption of data in JavaScript

Any suggestion.. what should I do.

I already tried few things but the result is not coming like for (public key)[http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/rsa/examples.html#convert] and (private key)[https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt]

thanks.

Update:

AIM: the aim is to send data from PHP server to client side with safety.

Update Edit :

how safe is it to keep private key in php code and giving public key to client side(javascript server node.js) on call... like for sending data from node.js server to php server.... is that safe without https ??

Or if we use https then we don't need to use this methed...??

Thanks

Comment: Storing private key in browser localStorage sounds a bit unconventional. If you are anyways controlling the servers, then why not to use a client-side certificate validation, when server would actually rely on SSL layer to validate that connecting client has proper certificates to access the content?

Comment: Questios is updated @VladimirM

Comment: In general, you have 2 participants: server in the network, and browser on user's machine.  If you are sending a key on call, it means that anybody listening for the HTTP traffic on your network will see your key)

Comment: but that is fine .. if somebody listens my key because that is public key .... whats the problem in listening about public key...

Comment: i will send public key from server to browser and browser will encrypt data with that public key and send back it to server.... server will decrypt the data with private key stored in php ...   is this not secure??

Comment: Well, perhaps, it is secure from point of view of that particular data item, providing that you have some other means to identify the origin of the message. But your site will have to take care of the replay attacks, cause your communication patterns would still be exposed.

Comment: and if i use https and methed just explainded above(like keeping private key in php)... can these two provide me an proper security??? like then i will be safe from replay attacks??

Comment: if you use https, then you probably don't need to encrypt messages by yourself on top of that. Depends on your application.

Comment: thanks very much.. you clear all my concepts...

Comment: It's hard to say much since you haven't posted any code but w.r.t. phpseclib and JSEncrypt interoperability...  see http://stackoverflow.com/q/18702563/569976

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your aim is to send data from php server to client side with safety, then consider using HTTPS.

What you're trying to do instead is extremely hard to get right. If you don't use HTTPS then it's pointless because your visitors won't be able to know who they are talking to and whether the key generation and decryption code is trustworthy. If you're using HTTPS then you already send data from php server to client side with safety (using private and public keys) and encrypting it once more wouldn't do anything.

If you are trying to protect that secret from other JavaScript code running in the browser, it will still not do anything because having the private key, encryption algorithm and encrypted message in your browser is not safer than having it in clear text.

Additionally, there is a lot of room for subtle errors in key generation, key distribution, the encryption algorithm, handling the encrypted message etc. Even if you could do all of that correctly, what you would get is at most what you already have with HTTPS.

And don't think it's easy - OpenSSL with good intentions and experienced developers is probably a world record holder for [the number of CVE entries](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=openssl) because this stuff is extremely hard to get right.

Make sure you read this classic article:

- [JavaScript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Also worth reading:

- [What’s wrong with in-browser cryptography?](https://tonyarcieri.com/whats-wrong-with-webcrypto)

Comment: thanks for your answer.. its the best.. which i have heard till now....

Comment: i have an another question to you.... how safe is it to keep  private key in php code and giving public key to client side(javascript server node.js) on call... like for sending data from node.js server to php server.... is that safe without https .... ???

Comment: @ManpreetOberoi Without https there is always a risk that the key can be changed in transit or that the client is not sure that it is talking with the trusted server. It's hard to get everything right to make it secure if you do everything yourself. But you can use https (with a free certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/), you can use ssh, you can use [encryption in ZeroMQ](http://hintjens.com/blog:49), you can use [encryption in RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html), you can use encrypted websocket over https - there are some solutions available that you may be able to use here.